# PySide.QtGui.QListWidget' object has no attribute 'setItemSelected'

Tags: python, pyside, qlistwidget

Extremely confused here...  trying to select all items in a QListWidget.  Strangely enough I have done this before fine with this code, but this time it is barking back at me?

```
# Error: 'PySide.QtGui.QListWidget' object has no attribute 'setItemSelected'
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 2, in <module>
#   ...............
#     self.locListWidget.setItemSelected(item, True)
# AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QListWidget' object has no attribute 'setItemSelected' # 

    if (sizeDimensionLocators > 0):
        for loc in dimensionLocators:
            self.locListWidget.addItem(loc)

    for i in range(self.locListWidget.count()):
        item = self.locListWidget.item(i)
        self.locListWidget.setItemSelected(item, True)    <---------- Issue Here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QListWidget doesn't have a `setItemSelected`:

- https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QListWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.QListWidget
- http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#selectedItems

You can do this though:

- `item.setSelected(true)`
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#setSelected

You might also need to review the selection mode:

- https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractItemView.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractItemView.setSelectionMode

Comment: If I do : self.ui.listWidget_path.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
  item_[0].setSelected(True)  ... nothing happens